GeoServer, CSS Styling, SVG parameters
I have a working SLD 1.1. on GeoServer 2.24.1
Part of SLD calls a parametric SVG image (green fill (#335b239) and red stroke(#ff0000)):
<!--Parametric SVG-->
<se:ExternalGraphic>
 <se:OnlineResource xlink:href="util/arrow_01_11i.svg?fill=%2335b239&amp;fill- 
 opacity=1&amp;outline=%23ff0000&amp;outline-opacity=1&amp;outline-width=8" xlink:type="simple"/>
 <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
</se:ExternalGraphic>

Because of complexity of the whole SLD (500+ rows) I want to translate it to CSS styling, here is the corresponding part of CSS styling code, where I want to call image in svg format:
  mark: url("util/arrow_01_11i.svg");
  mark-mime: "image/svg+xml";
  mark-fill: #35b239;
  mark-stroke: #ff0000;
  mark-stroke-width: 8px;
  

The result is black svg image (stroke and fill), that means all parameters:
  mark-fill: #35b239;
  mark-stroke: #ff0000;
  mark-stroke-width: 8px;

are ignored for sure.
if I call the svg image in CSS styling with:
  mark: url("util/arrow_01_11i.svg?fill=%2335b239&amp;fill- 
 opacity=1&amp;outline=%23000000&amp;outline-opacity=1&amp;outline-width=8");
  mark-mime: "image/svg+xml";

the result is green, which means parameters for outline are ignored.
What is the solution, how to write a css in that case in order all parameters will be taken into account?

You will find that a comparable CSS style will produce several times the size of SLD when converted back (as GeoServer does).

@IanTurton, you mean that converted SLD (from CSS) would be bigger than the original one? Nevertheless, any hint how to write css for my problem?

I would guess it will be 10 or more times bigger, and slower. I have no idea how to write the CSS, might be worth turning logging up or attaching a debugger
